# Does 'heroku restart' automatically calls the initializers in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, initializer

I've recently added some codes in the initialiser file of my rails application. Like any other rails app, I have to restart the app for it to call the initializers again. Does 'heroku restart' does the same thing (after committing the files etc.)? If not, what's the correct method to run the initialisers files in heroku? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pushing your app a new slug is compiled and started, so your rails app gets basically restarted every time you push a new version. `heroku restart` will let you restart your processes without pushing and should be done for example after migrating your database with `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

initializers are run when the application is launched. restarting the application stops it, then launches it.. so yes. :)